# Make histogram from data in python

Tags: python, histogram

I am trying to make a histogram from data saved in a .dat file: I have made other types of plots, but when trying to make the histogram i receive an error: ValueError: x has only one data point. bins or range kwarg must be given.
The table definitely has (many) more than one data point!
code below...

```
import numpy as  np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=open('/24_5_15b.dat','r')

header0=a.readline()

W1=[]
W2=[]

for line in a:
    line=line.strip()
    columns=line.split()
    W1=float(columns[13])
    W2=float(columns[15])

    w1=np.asarray(W1)
    w2=np.asarray(W2)   

    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(w1, 20, normed=1, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)

plt.show()
```

When I ask to print w1 it prints all the values. All the numbers are floats - would this make a difference?
Thanks...

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your data file (or its contents) so we can see what it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of this, you are trying to plot a histogram with the first line:

```
for line in a:
    ...
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(w1, 20, normed=1, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
```

to make a histogram, you need to pass all of the data, not one at a time.

I would recommend using `genfromtxt` for this too, with which you can use something like:

```
a = np.genfromtxt('/24_5_15b.dat')  # delimiter is " " by default
w1 = a[:,13]
w2 = a[:,15]

plt.hist(w1, ...)
```